# add a title row on top of each data pairs sets

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv that look like this:

[image]

I use this code:

```
pairs_ = dict()

with open('text2.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, j in re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', file.read()):
        pairs_.setdefault(i, []).extend([i, j])

df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values())
```

to make the pairs aligned in parallel.\

[image]

however I need to add the `*** Golden value for Channel[%d] , CE[%d] ***` on top of every set before the `Layer_00`

[image]

does anyone know how to achieve it? (the number of sets maybe different, this is just an example of 3 sets)

Answer (score 0):

Just create your headers in a list and pass that to DataFrame, remembering to leave a gap for your intermediate columns.  That won't be possible using the mechanism you have now, where you do everything in one `re.findall` call.  You'll have to process line by line so you can extract the headers.  This is untested:

```
pairs_ = dict()
titles = []

with open('text2.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('***'):
            titles.extend( [line.rstrip(),str(len(titles))] )
        else:
            for i, j in re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', line):
                pairs_.setdefault(i, []).extend([i, j])

df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values(), columns=titles )
```

Comment: if I want to add another row of header as numbers starting from 0 on top of the 'columns=titles' we created, how should I do it?   I use the 'df.columns =range(len(df.columns))' however it will overwrite the 'columns=titles'  we had.

Comment: pandas supports one row of headers.  I suppose you could insert a new row after you fill in the matrix.