# exclude the column header when selecting the column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am plotting with `xtick` using:

```
plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(df[0])), labels=df[0], rotation=45)
```

However, I need to exclude the first item of the column, which is the header of that column:

[image: exclude the 0]

Otherwise I get:

```
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Your pic is really similar with questions asked by User 
[chen boway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15621727/chen-boway). Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362687. Is this an Coincidence? BTW, chen boway has never accepted any answers. Please view  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` to exclude first item from column 0

```
plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(df.loc[1:,0])), labels=df.loc[1:,0], rotation=45)
```